# TYPO3 - display one page from pagetree only

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a problem whose solution is certainly very simple, but it does not come to my mind at the moment :/

I have a multi-domain TYPO3 (6.1) installation and in one of the websites I need to temporarily show only one subpage, and over the rest of the pages I will work/update so I can not delete them. It is important that someone after entering a URL or going to the page from the Google search results has not opened this page, and has been redirected to this temporary.

I've tried the mount points but something does not work ...

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange the domain-records.
Make a new page on it's own (independent from the configuration of the domain it should replace). so it is a root-page. give it a domain record and disable the domain record of the pagetree it should replace.

Be aware to change the rootpageid configuration in realurl.

You also may need a special configuration for 404 handling for this domain as the most requests will be a 404 (or better 503).

And hurry up to update your system. TYPO3 6.1 is out of service for a long time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i hope that there is another way, without realurl config changes. Of course it's no problem, so I'll do that. Outdated T3 - i know, but there is more complicated than u think - my client doesn't want to pay for it :P